# Recorded audio to text

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am implementing an web application that convert **recorded audio** to **text** that can run in **chrome** and **Mozilla Firefox** browsers. There are many api's that can be run only in chrome. I am not able to find such api or library that can be implemented in both. I am implementing my application in J2EE.

So can anybody tell me if this can be done using **JavaScript** or **Java**.

Comment: [This](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) is a speech recognition library in Java. (linked page includes example usage, it even shows how to put a .wav file and run voice recognition on that) I've played around with that library before, it worked pretty well.

Comment: @leroydev thank you for your response, i hope your suggestion will solve my problem.

Comment: @leroydev i am getting following error while running **TranscriberDemo** : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/cmu/sphinx/api/Configuration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**. Can you help me why am i getting this?

Comment: Check out this question and the top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error

Comment: @leroydev Is this work with java7? Because i cant upgrade to java8.